# Filter column names dataframe by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sql-like

I want to filter my data and remove the column with the name 'Yesterday' in it . By using Dplyr package in r

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP is tagged with `sql-like`; something similar exists in the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
df[!names(df) %like% 'Yesterday']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `starts_with` if you want to remove columns that start with `'Yesterday'`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(-starts_with('Yesterday'))
```

Or `matches` if you want to remove columns that have `'Yesterday'` anywhere in their name.

```
df %>% select(-matches('Yesterday'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Sr.No=1:2,
                 Today_Age=11:12,
                 Yesterday_Age=c(21,32),
                 Today_Height=c(23,22),
                 Yesterday_Height=c(21,33))
#Code
new <- df %>% select(!contains('Yesterday'))
```

Output:

```
  Sr.No Today_Age Today_Height
1     1        11           23
2     2        12           22
```